# Why am I getting a KeyError when attempting to use an Enum as a Dictionary Key in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For context, I have the following file structure:

```
Helpers.Py
Constants.Py
/Tests
 - Test_Helpers.Py
```

I defined an Enum in Constants like so:

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class HelperEnum(Enum):
    ValueOne = auto()
    ValueTwo = auto()
```

Then used it as a Dictionary Key in Helpers.Py like so:

```
from Constants import HelperEnum

class ClassOne:
   def __init__(self):
      self.dictionary = { HelperEnum.ValueOne: "TEMP" }
```

But when I try to access it from Tests/Test_Helpers.py, it doesn't work.

```
from .. import Helpers
from .. import Constants

Helpers.ClassOne().dictionary[Constants.HelperEnum.ValueOne]
```

Retuns KeyError. I can see in the debugger that the enum.Name and .Value are the same, so why is there a KeyError?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Can you [edit] your question to include a [mre]?